# Difference between iterating over JArray and JArray.Children()

Tags: c#, json.net

```
var jarr = new JArray{new JObject{{"a", "1"}}, new JObject{{"b", "2"}}, new JObject{{"c", "3"}}};

foreach (var item in jarr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

foreach (var item in jarr.Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Both foreach loops print the same on Console.
What is the difference between iterating over `JArray` and `JArray.Children()`?

Comment: They're the same for `JArray` but different for [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm): `JObject.GetEnumerator()` is of type `public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>> GetEnumerator()` while `Children()` is of type `public override JEnumerable<JToken> Children()`.  Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mnQRHQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, you can see the relevant [source code here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JArray.cs).

The `GetEnumerator` method (which would be called by the foreach loop) of `JArray` just returns the enumerator of its `Children` anyway (around line 327):

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A <see cref="IEnumerator{T}"/> of <see cref="JToken"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
/// </returns>
public IEnumerator<JToken> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Children().GetEnumerator();
}
```

The reason why both ways of iterating over the `JArray` exist is because `Children` is declared in `JToken`, so all its subclasses gotta have it. It also makes sense for `JArray` to implement `IList<JToken>`, which means that it also implements `IEnumerable<JToken>`, allowing you to iterate over it directly with a foreach loop.